# How to use same model name in different Json array in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have two Json arrays like given below.

```
Items: any[]; Item: any = {};
```

Both array having same property name ItemName; Items array contains list of item details. If I select one item from Items array and copy to Item. When I update the value from Item it reflects in Items also. How to block this in Angular 2/4

Comment: don't push the object itseft, just a copy:items.push({name:element.name,desc:element:desc}) NOT items.push(element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract and make a deep clone of your selected item and manipulate it instead of the item in the array. You can do it like this:

```
Items: any[]; // Your original array
Item: any = {}; // One of the items in the previous array

selectedItem: any = Object.assign({}, Item); // use this item instead of the previous one.
```

Hope it helps! :)